# ¿Cómo implementar operador NOT IN en un For Each de Genexus?

Tags: genexus, foreach, genexus15, genexusxev3

En una cláusula **Where** de un For Each, se puede usar el operador IN de la siguiente manera:

```
For Each
    Where id IN &IdsCollection
    //código
EndFor
```

¿Cómo se puede escribir la condición **Where** para buscar elementos que no estén en la colección? La condición `Where id Not In &IdsCollection` no es posible.

**Lo que se busca resolver es** poder recorrer en un For Each una lista de elementos que pueden repetirse, agregándolos a una collection. Excluyendo los ya agregados en el Where para no agregar repetidos a la collection.

```
&collectionAtributo.clear()
For Each
    where NOT atributo IN &collectionAtributo //No funciona con atributo char?

    &collectionAtributo.Add(atributo.Trim())
EndFor
```

Donde atributo es del tipo character con formato "xx,xxx". Ejemplo: "12,345"

Answer (score 0):

Para usar un not in en un **Where** de un For Each debes utilizar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
For Each
    Where NOT id IN &IdsCollection
    //código
EndFor
```

Comment: Bien  @guido-lorenzatti, la verdad lo había probado de esa manera. Por lo tanto me estoy dando cuenta que si el id es char no funciona. 
Mi where es el siguiente:
`where NOT  charId  IN  &charIdsCollection `

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo no funciona? ¿Será por espacios en los char o mayúsculas? Trata hacerle a todos los elementos de &charIdsCollection .Trim().ToUpper() y también a charId en el where: where NOT charId.Trim().ToUpper() IN &charIdsCollection

Comment: He probado varias formas y no lo consigo. Lo que busco es que no se recorran repetidos en el for. Los idChar tienen la forma "123,456"  por lo tanto no influiría el toUppper. Pero se recorren repetidos porque en la collection quedan: 
["33,542","33,543","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","1,611637","76,56","76,56","76,56","33,542"]

Comment: y `where NOT HistCmbTabClave.Trim() IN &collectionHistCmbTabClave` da error al generar (Java):
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
com\app\objeto.java:101: error: ')' expected
         if ( ! GXutil.trim( A1164idChar) IN AV20collectionidChar )
com\app\objeto.java:101: error: ';' expected
         if ( ! GXutil.trim( A1164idChar) IN AV20collectionidChar )

com\app\objeto.java:101: error: variable declaration not allowed here
         if ( ! GXutil.trim( A1164idChar) IN AV20collectionidChar )

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar el operador NOT IN en un bucle For Each de GeneXus, puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
For Each &variable
Where &variable.Attribute NOT IN (valor1, valor2, valor3, ...)
EndFor
```

Donde &variable es la variable que se está iterando en el bucle y Attribute es el atributo de esa variable que se desea comparar con los valores especificados en la lista (valor1, valor2, valor3, etc.).

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos una variable de tipo Customer llamada &customer y queremos iterar sobre todos los clientes que no tienen el país "Argentina" o "Brasil":

```
For Each &customer
Where &customer.Country NOT IN ("Argentina", "Brasil")
EndFor
```

Comment: Hola @mauricio-lopez gracias, pero necesito hacerlo con una collection como en el ejemplo porque se va cargando en el for. Es de esta manera que no logro resolverlo.